# how to join multilble table in multiple database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have 4 tables in 4 databases and want to filter on max value by unique id and datetime today morning 6:00 AM to Next morning 6:00 AM and output as another table /view.

I tired to join table according to this requirement.

```
USE PLC_WTR1
GO
SELECT  PLCTAG_PLC1_WTR1S001_PCReadJob_Tar_JobNo_Value,
MAX (Section_WTR1S001_CurrentJob_BatchLog_WeightActualProduced_Value) FROM WTR1
WHERE CAST (DateAndTime AS time) >= '05:59:00.000'
OR   CAST (DateAndTime AS time)  <= '05:59:00.000' 
GROUP BY PLCTAG_PLC1_WTR1S001_PCReadJob_Tar_JobNo_Value 

USE PLC_WTR2
GO
SELECT  PLCTAG_PLC1_WTR2S001_PCReadJob_Tar_JobNo_Value,
MAX (Section_WTR2S001_CurrentJob_BatchLog_WeightActualProduced_Value) FROM WTR2
WHERE CAST (DateAndTime AS time) >= '05:59:00.000'
OR   CAST (DateAndTime AS time)  <= '05:59:00.000' 
GROUP BY PLCTAG_PLC1_WTR2S001_PCReadJob_Tar_JobNo_Value

USE PLC_WTR3
GO
SELECT  PLCTAG_PLC1_WTR3S001_PCReadJob_Tar_JobNo_Value,
MAX (Section_WTR3S001_CurrentJob_BatchLog_WeightActualProduced_Value) FROM WTR3
WHERE CAST (DateAndTime AS time) >= ' 05:59:00.000'
OR   CAST (DateAndTime AS time)  <= '05:59:00.000' 
GROUP BY PLCTAG_PLC1_WTR3S001_PCReadJob_Tar_JobNo_Value 

USE PLC_WTR4
GO
SELECT  PLCTAG_PLC1_WTR4S001_PCReadJob_Tar_JobNo_Value,
MAX (Section_WTR4S001_CurrentJob_BatchLog_WeightActualProduced_Value) FROM WTR4
WHERE DateAndTime >= '2019-04-17 05:59:00.000'
OR   DateAndTime  <= '2019-04-18 05:59:00.000' 
GROUP BY PLCTAG_PLC1_WTR4S001_PCReadJob_Tar_JobNo_Value
```

Comment: Are the 4 databases on the same database server?

Answer (score 0):

You can put **database** and **schema** name in the start of **table** name. Probably you want a `union` result. Another point is that you are filtering **on time part only**, so it will bring the rows of other days (other than today) as well having same time.

Following is an example how to use multiple databases in 1 query,

```
select col1 from database1.dbo.table1
union all
select col1 from database2.dbo.table2
```

Notice that I am using `dbo` schema.